# div with content align out of order with respect to div without content

Tags: html, css

**In the below code, the  element with the content is out of order with respect  to the other  elements without content. This doesn't occur when all the elements in the row has some content in them. Any idea why this is happening? (Thanks in advance for the help).**

```html
<style>
 button {
  background-color: #ffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

<div>
   <div>
    <button> </button>
    <button> </button>
    <button> </button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <button> </button>
    <button> X </button>
    <button> </button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <button> </button>
    <button> </button>
    <button> </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It could be a user agent style for `<button>` elements.  Maybe it's defaulting to a specific `vertical-align` for example?  Does setting that style explicitly help?

Comment: yes, changing vertical-align for button worked. But I still don't get why it was happening.

Comment: I checked all "computed" values on the X... Nothing. Ok there is a little padding given by user agent, but 0 6px only. Now yes computed vertical-align is 'baseline' . Putting value vertical-align: text-top; worked. You can also put div > dic with display flex. That works too. I think it's really to do with the "line-height" really taken by the font at 50px... More or less (don't blame me it's not a real calculation), the line-height would be between 1.5 to 1.75 the font. Which gives the space on top with font on baseline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add property vertical-align: top; to button styles:

```
button {
  background-color: #ffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```css
.button-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #ffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button></button>
    <button>X</button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```